# How to temporarily stop and start Gnome?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, session

I am looking to just force my box to end all GUI instances for server usage. I want to be able to start them back up again for desktop usage later on.

**I have tried:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop
sudo service gdm stop
sudo service gnome stop
sudo service gdm stop gdm: unrecognized service
sudo service gnome stop gnome: unrecognized service
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop sudo: /etc/init.d/gdm: command not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precise Pangolin uses `lightdm` instead of `gdm`, so something like the following should work.

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Comment: For Gnome it is " sudo service gdm3 stop "

Answer (score 3):

To stop lightdm , you can do

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

to start lightdm

```
sudo start lightdm
```

Source :[LightDM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)